# How to add multiple TextBox follow by DataGridView.Columns.Count and column data.TQ

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, textbox

```cs
//...
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadData();
        textBoxFill();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        SqlConnection SCConnect = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=T8;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        SCConnect.Open();
        StringBuilder SBBuilder = new StringBuilder("Select * from Table8");
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(SBBuilder.ToString(), SCConnect);
        SqlCommandBuilder SCB = new SqlCommandBuilder(SDA);
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        SDA.Fill(DT);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;
    }

    private void textBoxFill()
    {
        TextBox TB = new TextBox();
        int A = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            panel1.Controls.Add(TB);
            TB.Location = new Point(10, (A * 20));
            TB.Top = A * 28;
            TB.Size = new Size(200, 50);
            TB.Margin = new Padding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        }
        A = A + 1;
    }
}
```

How do I add multiple TextBox follow by DataGridView.Columns.Count and 
each TextBox to fill in each DataGridView columns data.TQ?

[image: add multiple textbox]

Comment: Move `TextBox TB = new TextBox();` and `A = A + 1;` inside the loop. You're setting the Location to a value, Top (again) to another and none of them matches the (hypothetical) `TextBox.Height.`. I suggest to add those controls to a FlowLayoutPanel instead of a simple Panel. You should dispose of the data objects you create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing after looking at the previous duplicate post, that this may be what you are looking for. It may help you if you explained the overall picture as this seems like on odd thing to do since the data is already in the grid and the user can edit it, I am not sure why you would do this data “duplication” in the panel.

However, it does appear you want to have the textboxes correspond to the currently “selected” row in the grid. Such that there will be one textbox for each column in the grid. Initially, you do know how many columns the data may contain. Therefore, you need to dynamically create the textbox’s in the panel.

One approach to “bind” each textbox to a column of the currently selected row in the grid may be accomplished by “binding” each textbox to a particular column in the `DataTable` that is used as the `DataSource` to the grid. Each textbox has a property called…`DataBindings`. This property will allow you to “bind” the textbox to a particular column in the `DataTable`. Below is an example.

To help, given we have the data, I suggest a method `AddTextBoxesToPanel(DataTable dt)` … that takes a `DataTable` and loops through the columns of that table and creates a textbox for each column AND adds the “binding” for that column to that textbox. With this approach, no extra code will be necessary to fill the text boxes when the user selects different rows.

```
private void AddTextBoxesToPanel(DataTable dt) {
  panel1.Controls.Clear();
  panel1.AutoScroll = true;
  panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(0, (dt.Columns.Count * 23) + 15);
  TextBox curTB;
  int y = 10;
  foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns) {
    curTB = GetTextBox(10, y);
    curTB.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", dt, col.ColumnName));
    panel1.Controls.Add(curTB);
    y += 23;
  }
}
```

Above, we assume this may be called more than once and need to “clear” any previous textboxs in the panel. Set the panel to be scrollable, then start the loop through the columns to add the textboxes to the panel. The `GetTextBox` method (below) simply gets a new `TextBox` with the desired location. Lastly, we set the `DataBinding` for “that” textbox to point to “that” column. `curTB.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", dt, col.ColumnName));`

```
private TextBox GetTextBox(int xLoc, int yLoc) {
  TextBox TB = new TextBox {
    Text = "",
    Location = new Point(xLoc, yLoc),
    Size = new Size(150, 50),
    Margin = new Padding(10),
    Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left
  };
  return TB;
}
```

Below is a complete example using the above method. The Forms `Load` method to fill a `DataTable` with 10 columns and 20 rows, then use that `DataTable` as a `DataSource` to the grid. Then call the method above to set the textboxes into the panel.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  FillGrid(10, 20);
  AddTextBoxesToPanel((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);
}
```

A method to generate some data for testing.

```
private void FillGrid(int totalColumns, int totRows) {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  // add columns
  for (int i = 0; i < totalColumns; i++) {
    dt.Columns.Add("Col" + i, typeof(string));
  }
  // add rows
  object[] data = new object[totalColumns];
  for (int row = 0; row < totRows; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < totalColumns; col++) {
      data[col] = "Col" + col + "Row" + row;
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(data);
  }
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Hope this helps.